# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT & DELETE while performing update & delete

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

Code In web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth','admin']], function(){
    Route::put('/role-register-update/{id}', 'Admin\DashboardController@registerupdate');
    Route::delete('/role-delete/{id}', 'Admin\DashboardController@registerdelete');
});
```

Code in DashboardController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{

    public function registerupdate(Request $request, $id){
        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->name = $request->input('name');
        $user->phone = $request->input('phone');
        $user->email = $request->input('email');
        $user->userType = $request->input('userType');
        $user->update();
        return \redirect('/user_profile')->with('success', 'Your Data Is Updated');
    }

    public function registerdelete($id){
        $user = User::findOrfail($id);
        $user->delete();
        return \redirect('/user_profile')->with('success', 'Your Data Is Deleted');
    }
}
```

Code of Edit Form

```
<form action="/role-register-update/{{ $user->id }}" method="POST">
                            {{ @csrf_field() }} {{ @method_field('PUT') }}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" value="{{ $user->name }}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" value="{{ $user->phone }}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email Id" value="{{ $user->email }}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="role">Role</label>
                                <select name="userType" class="form-control" id="userType">
                                    <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
                                    <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                                    <option value="user">Internal User</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Submit</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <a href='../user_profile' class="btn btn-outline-warning">Cancel</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

code Of Delete Form Data

```
<form method="POST" action="/role-delete/{{ $user->id }}">
                                        {{ csrf_field() }} {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Danger</button>
                                    </form>
```

Update & Delete operation not performing on the localhost In Laravel 5.8.
It throws the error for the update is-
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT.

& same error for delete
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: DELETE.

I am not getting the solution, please help

Comment: Set `type="submit"` instead.

Comment: Thank You :) It Is now working correctly both update & delete functionality

Comment: Good. You can accept and vote up answer I left there. I also mention one more thing from your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have correct form functionality, your button should have type of `submit`.

I.e. in form for update

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Submit</button>
```

or in form for delete:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Danger</button>
```

Side note, your cancel link have `../user_profile` href attribute. 
You should consider not using those kind of traversable location strings and you'll avoid lot of pita later. Insted, best way would be to use [route name provided by framework](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#named-routes) or just path relative to URL root but with leading slash

For example:

```
<a href='/user_profile' class="btn btn-outline-warning">Cancel</a>
```

But again, best way and correct way from programming point and from maintenance point of view would be using named routes

```
 <a href='{{ route('route.name.set.in.routes.web.file') }}' class="btn btn-outline-warning">Cancel</a>
```